# datetuil results in wrong utc offset when using lower case

Tags: python, datetime, python-dateutil

I'm trying to convert dates into different timezones using `dateutil`.
I've noticed, that using lower case letters when creating the `tz` objects is leading to incorrect timezones.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> from dateutil import tz

>>> tz.gettz('utc-6')
tzstr('utc-6')
>>> tz.gettz('UTC-6')
tzstr('UTC-6')
```

Up to this point, everything seems to be correct, however when passing the `tzstr` into a `datetime` object, the lower-case `tzstr` will apply the inverted offset. This happens to both, + and -, for all offsets.

I used `%z` to show the applied offset, but the issue is affecting all datetime operations.

```
>>> datetime.now(tz.gettz('UTC-6')).strftime('%z')
'-0600'

>>> datetime.now(tz.gettz('utc-6')).strftime('%z')
'+0600'
>>> datetime.now(tz.gettz('utc-06')).strftime('%z')
'+0600'
>>>
>>> datetime.now(tz.gettz('utc-8')).strftime('%z')
'+0800'
>>>
```

Is there a big oversight by myself, or is it indeed a bug in the package?
I couldn't find anything in the docs limiting the user input to capitalized UTC+X.

(Python version is `tags/v3.9.9:ccb0e6a` on Windows and `python-dateutil 2.8.2`, but occurs as well on Linux with python 2.8.2)

Comment: Does this also happen if you parse an actual date/time with UTC offset? Can't you just enforce uppercase to get the correct result? I mean, the correct spelling *is* UTC afaik.

Comment: When I call something like `parsed_date.astimezone(tz.gettz('utc+1'))` it is handled incorrectly as well.

Usually, the library throws errors or defaults to your local system time when trying to use non-existent timezones. None of that is the case, so this behaviour seems odd to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dateutil library, by default, diverges from POSIX-style time zones, which "use an inverted offset format, so normally GMT+3 would be parsed as an offset 3 hours behind GMT. The tzstr time zone object will parse this as an offset 3 hours ahead of GMT" ([dateutil documentation on dateutil.tz.tzstr()](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tz.html#dateutil.tz.tzstr)).

The library determines when to invert the offset by checking if your timezone abbreviation is either "UTC" or "GMT" (case sensitive), then multiplies the offset by -1. Because the check is case sensitive, the offset for "UTC-6" does properly get offset to -0600 but "utc-6" does not ([tzstr source code](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/blob/2.8.2/dateutil/tz/tz.py#L1091)).

```
# Here we break the compatibility with the TZ variable handling.
# GMT-3 actually *means* the timezone -3.
if res.stdabbr in ("GMT", "UTC") and not posix_offset:
    res.stdoffset *= -1
```

Regardless of if this was an intentional decision, with the current tzstr implementation, you should uppercase your timezone strings before passing them in to `gettz()`.

Comment: Great insight into the lib. This explains the seemingly odd behaviour.